# Current-fed Royer oscillator startup speed

Tags: oscillator, high-voltage, royer

I am trying to design a current-fed Royer oscillator based 5 kV supply that needs to start up fast and then decay fast. The goal is less than 100 ms for both startup and decay. The criteria are to reach at least 4.75 kV and 0.25 kV, respectively.
[image]

The trouble seems to be that if the load is lighter, the multiplier capacitors take longer to discharge and if the load is heavier, the startup takes longer. The real load for the application would be very light (just several pF capacitance), RL is used just to tune the above mentioned timing. The final design would include a feedback control loop to set the output voltage.

- Is 100ms realistic for the given criteria?
- Are there any particular components, values, topology tricks, etc. that can make a Royer oscillator start up faster?
- Can anything other than changing the load make the output voltage decay faster?
- The feedback control loop can only make things slow down, right?

Comment: Why is R4 = 10 k ?

Comment: @Antonio51 Because it should prevent the oscillator's L4 being short-circuited momentarily, this should make sure the oscillator does start up. So I have been told.

Comment: Ok. It does also slow down the rise of voltage output. I tried to simulate this circuit. No real success for high voltage. What are your results?

Comment: NB: the rising is something 200 V/ms. The fall time is slow, but it can be faster with the use of a switched load.

Answer (score 0):

You are charging lots of caps .Try to increase the frequency to underpin smaller caps .You could do MHz by using small mosfets .Remember that your diode pump diodes cant and dont discharge the caps ,your load does this and reducing the load resister wastes power .You could do an active discharge scheme to improve the fall time without wasting power.